# Query to find the time lapsed between status A to Status B

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to find number of days difference between change in status from 15 to 20 for the order 7658 (table name - ECOM_DATA)

```
ORD_NO   INT_ORD_LINE_STAT_EXP      STAT_DATE_ACT         STAT_DATE_EXP

 7658          15                 11-OCT-17 00:00:00    11-OCT-17 00:00:00
 7658          20                 16-OCT-17 00:00:00    16-OCT-17 00:00:00
```

Can someone suggest?? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Each database product has a different set of date arithmetic functions, so we need to know the database brand you are using to answer.  Or you could look up the date functions for your database.

Comment: iam using mysql db and table name is ECOM_DATA- i saw datediff function but how to use this so delivery_status field changes from  15 to 20 , STAT_DATE_ACT field changes from 11 Oct to 16 Oct , i want to calculate how many days elapsed for change in status from 15 to 20

Comment: OK.  datediff is what you want.  You need to select the row with status 20 in one sub-select and select the row with status 15 in another sub-select.  Join the two sub-selects on the key (order 7658) and use datediff on the two stat_date_act results.  If you show some sample data we can show a query to give you the result you want.  Read [ask], especially [mcve].

Comment: DELIVERY_STATUS = 15   STAT_DATE_ACT=11-OCT-17 00.00.00                DELIVERY_STATUS = 20   STAT_DATE_ACT=16-OCT-17 00.00.00

Answer (score 0):

Minimal set-up:

```
create table ecom_data
(
    ord_no                 integer,
    int_ord_line_stat_exp  integer,
    stat_date_act          timestamp
);

insert into ecom_data (ord_no, int_ord_line_stat_exp, stat_date_act) values (7658, 15, '2017-10-11');
insert into ecom_data (ord_no, int_ord_line_stat_exp, stat_date_act) values (7658, 20, '2017-10-16');
```

The query:

```
select
    a.ord_no,
    datediff(b.stat_date_act, a.stat_date_act) as days_between
from
    (
        select 
            ord_no,
            stat_date_act
        from
            ecom_data
        where 
            int_ord_line_stat_exp = 15
     ) a
     join
     (
        select 
            ord_no,
            stat_date_act
        from
            ecom_data
        where 
            int_ord_line_stat_exp = 20
     ) b
     on a.ord_no = b.ord_no
where
    a.ord_no = 7658;
```

The result:

```
+--------+--------------+
| ord_no | days_between |
+--------+--------------+
|   7658 |            5 |
+--------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there are thousands of rows and cant enter hard coded values

Comment: This query will return all the order numbers that have both a status of 15 and a status of 20.  I presume you can hard-code the status values?  If you want particular order numbers, or date ranges, or whatever, just add the appropriate where clause at the end of the query, just before the semi-colon.

Comment: I've edited the query to show how to select a particular order number.  Sounds like it would help you to invest some time in learning SQL.  It is very worthwhile.  A free resource is https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp; my contribution is http://www.thedatastudio.net.  There are many other resources available.